# Compare Two Objects And Get Key-Value Pairs Of Their Differences

Tags: javascript

Updated:

```
const hero1 = {
  name: 'Batman',
  realName: 'Bruce Wayne'
};
const hero2 = {
  name: 'false',
  realName: 'Bruce Wayne'
};

diff(oldobj, newobj) {
    const keys = Array.from(new Set([...Object.keys(oldobj),...Object.keys(newobj)]))
    const diff = Object.entries({...oldobj, ...newobj}).filter(([key]) => oldobj[key] !== newobj[key]);
    return Object.fromEntries(diff);
}
diff(hero1,hero2);
```

I'm trying to compare two objects (old/new) and return the difference in the new object

for an example:

Here is the code I have but it's not returning the key/value :

```
hasSameProps(oldobj, newobj ) {
  return Object.keys( oldobj ).every( function( prop ) {
    return newobj.hasOwnProperty( prop );
  });
}

deltaobj = {};
oldobj = { prop1: 'hello', prop2: 'peeps'  },
newobj = { prop1: 'hi', prop2: 'world'  };

console.log(hasSameProps(oldobj, newobj));
```

Comment: Can you show what you EXPECT to be returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method will only tell you if there *are* any differences.

Another way it could have been written is like this, which might be a bit clearer:

```
hasSameProps(oldobj, newobj) {
  return Array.from(
    new Set([...Object.keys(oldobj),...Object.keys(newobj)])  // all combined keys
  ).every((key) => oldobj[key] === newobj[key])
}
```

To return the differences, we can write a slightly different version:

```
diff(oldobj, newobj) {
    const keys = Array.from(new Set([...Object.keys(oldobj),...Object.keys(newobj)]))
    const diff = Object.entries({...oldobj, ...newobj}).filter(([key]) => oldobj[key] !== newobj[key]);
    return Object.fromEntries(diff);
}
```

[Live Demo v1](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/DEJUCokL1BXdDZFkGNJg/src/app.js?p=stories)

Comment: thank you, when I run the diff function getting this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'` I could not find where you missing in the code

Comment: @NickKahn It shouldn't have had the `function` keyword in there; I wrote the mockup in NodeJS.

Comment: got it, I used the diff function and it's returning the true/false, instead of key/value

Comment: never mind, it's late here :) i will test more tomorrow.

Comment: @NickKahn You set the new name to "false", so it returned false. Here, I wrote up a webcomponents link for you when you get to this tomorrow: https://webcomponents.dev/edit/DEJUCokL1BXdDZFkGNJg/src/app.js?p=stories

Comment: @NickKahn And a fun new enhanced version for you to peruse: https://webcomponents.dev/edit/6ZARev3QoGYxMhkoRfAB/src/app.html?p=stories

Comment: wow looks amazing thanks for doing that.